# Extending ggplot2 with a custom geometry for sf objects

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, ggproto

I am trying to create a new geometry for `ggplot` as described [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/extending-ggplot2.html#inheriting-from-an-existing-geom), while adapting it to deal with Simple Features objects.

As an example, let's take the same exercise of plotting the convex hull of a set of points. Thus, I wrote a new `geom_envelope()` function borrowing elements from [`geom_sf()`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-sf.R) and a corresponding `GeomEnvelope` `ggproto` object that performs the computation overriding the `draw_group()` method (since I want a single polygon for the full set of points).

However, I must be missing something, since I can't get the polygon plotted. I've been trying for a while but I either get errors or nothing plotted.

```
library(sf); library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)

Npts <- 10
pts <- matrix(runif(2*Npts), ncol = 2) %>% 
  st_multipoint() %>% 
  st_sfc() %>% 
  st_cast("POINT") %>% 
  st_sf()

GeomEnvelope <- ggproto(
  "GeomEnvelope", GeomSf,

  required_aes = "geometry",

  default_aes = aes(
    shape = NULL,
    colour = "grey20",
    fill = "white",
    size = NULL,
    linetype = 1,
    alpha = 0.5,
    stroke = 0.5
  ),

  draw_key = draw_key_polygon,

  draw_group = function(data, panel_params, coord) {
    n <- nrow(data)
    if (n <= 2) return(grid::nullGrob())

    gp <- gpar(
      colour = data$colour,
      size = data$size,
      linetype = data$linetype,
      fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha),
      group = data$group,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

    geometry <- sf::st_convex_hull(st_combine(sf::st_as_sf(data)))

    sf::st_as_grob(geometry, pch = data$shape, gp = gp)

  }
)


geom_envelope <- function(
  mapping = aes(),
  data = NULL,
  position = "identity",
  na.rm = FALSE,
  show.legend = NA,
  inherit.aes = TRUE,
  ...) {

  if (!is.null(data) && ggplot2:::is_sf(data)) {
    geometry_col <- attr(data, "sf_column")
  }
  else {
    geometry_col <- "geometry"
  }
  if (is.null(mapping$geometry)) {
    mapping$geometry <- as.name(geometry_col)
  }
  c(
    layer(
      geom = GeomEnvelope,
      data = data,
      mapping = mapping,
      stat = "identity",
      position = position,
      show.legend = if (is.character(show.legend))
        TRUE
      else
        show.legend,
      inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
      params = list(
        na.rm = na.rm,
        legend = if (is.character(show.legend))
          show.legend
        else
          "polygon",
        ...
      )
    ),
    coord_sf(default = TRUE)
  )
}

ggplot(pts) + geom_sf() + geom_envelope() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: @facu Have you checked this line `draw_key = draw_key_polygon,`? The function `draw_key_polygon()` signature requires data. On another note, please add comments in your code to show what the function or sub-functions are doing or meant to do.. It's difficult to parse it otherwise.

Comment: @mnm, yes, I borrowed the line `draw_key` from the [tutorial on extending ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/extending-ggplot2.html#collective-geoms). Actually, I borrowed most of other functions from somewhere else, not always with full understanding of their role. Thus the lack of comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this is your actual use case (rather than a simplified example of it), then I'd say the essential part of what you are looking for is a custom **Stat**, not a custom **Geom**. Data computations / manipulations should happen within the former.

(For reference, I usually look at the code in [`GeomBoxplot`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-boxplot.r) / [`StatBoxplot`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-boxplot.r) to figure out where things should happen, since that use case includes a bunch of calculations for quantiles / outliers, as well as the combination of different grob elements that accept various aesthetic mappings.)

Data with random seed for reproducibility:

```
set.seed(123)

pts <- matrix(runif(2*Npts), ncol = 2) %>% 
  st_multipoint() %>% 
  st_sfc() %>% 
  st_cast("POINT") %>% 
  st_sf()
```

## Basic demonstration

The following `StatEnvelope` would take the dataset passed to the relevant geom layer, and convert the collection of geometry values within each group (if no grouping aesthetic is specified, the entire dataset will be treated as one group) into a convex hull:

```
StatEnvelope <- ggproto(
  "StatEnvelope", Stat,
  required_aes = "geometry",
  compute_group = function(data, scales) {
    if(nrow(data) <= 2) return (NULL)
    data %>%
      group_by_at(vars(-geometry)) %>%
      summarise(geometry = sf::st_convex_hull(sf::st_combine(geometry))) %>%
      ungroup()
  }
)

ggplot(pts) + 
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(stat = StatEnvelope, 
          alpha = 0.5, color = "grey20", fill = "white", size = 0.5) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: plot]

## Upgrade

The above approach, using the existing `geom_sf`, does a perfectly passable job at creating the envelope. If we want to specify some default aesthetic parameters, rather than repeat within every instance of `geom_sf`, we *still* don't need to define a new Geom. A function that modifies the existing `geom_sf` would do fine.

```
geom_envelope <- function(...){
  suppressWarnings(geom_sf(stat = StatEnvelope, 
                           ..., # any aesthetic argument specified in the function 
                                # will take precedence over the default arguments
                                # below, with suppressWarning to mute warnings on
                                # any duplicated aesthetics
                           alpha = 0.5, color = "grey20", fill = "white", size = 0.5))
}

# outputs same plot as before
ggplot(pts) + 
  geom_sf() +
  geom_envelope() +
  theme_bw()

# with different aesthetic specifications for demonstration
ggplot(pts) + 
  geom_sf() +
  geom_envelope(alpha = 0.1, colour = "brown", fill = "yellow", size = 3) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: plot 2]

---

## Explanation for what's going on for the code posted in the question

When I mess around with customised ggproto objects, one useful trick I like to use is to insert print statements within every function I modify, e.g. `"setting up parameters"`, or `"drawing panel, step 3"`, etc. This allows me to have a good idea of what's happening beneath the hood, and track where things went wrong when the function (inevitably) returns an error on the 1st / 2nd / ... / nth try.

In this case, if we insert `print("draw group")` at the beginning of `GeomEnvelope`'s `draw_group` function before running `ggplot(pts) + geom_sf() + geom_envelope() + theme_bw()`, we'll observe the absence of any printed message in the console. In other words, **the `draw_group` function was never called**, so any data manipulation defined therein has no effect on the output.

There are several `draw_*` functions in `Geom*`, which can be confusing when we want to make modifications. From the [code for `Geom`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-.r), we can see the hierarchy is as follows:

1. `draw_layer` (which includes a `do.call(self$draw_panel, args)` line)
2. `draw_panel` (which includes a `self$draw_group(group, panel_params, coord, ...)` line)
3. `draw_group` (which is not implemented for `Geom`).

So `draw_layer` triggers `draw_panel`, and `draw_panel` triggers `draw_group`. (Mirroring this, in `Stat`, `compute_layer` triggers `compute_panel` and `compute_panel` triggers `compute_group`.)

`GeomSf`, which inherits from `Geom` (code [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-sf.R)), overrides `Geom`'s `draw_panel` function with a chunk of code that returns a `sf_grob(...)`, and ***DOES NOT*** trigger `draw_group`.

Consequently, when `GeomEnvelope` inherits `GeomSf`'s `draw_panel` function, nothing in its `draw_group` function is going to matter. What's drawn in the plot depends on `draw_panel`, and the `geom_envelope` layer in the question performs essentially the same task as `geom_sf`, plotting each individual point separately. If you remove / comment out the `geom_sf` layer, you'll see the same points; just with color = "grey20", alpha = 0.5, etc., as specified in `GeomSf`'s `default_aes`.

*(Note: `fill = "white"` isn't in use, because `geom_sf` defaults to `GeomPoint`'s default aesthetics for point data, which means it inherits `GeomPoint`'s `pch = 19` for its point shape, and plots a solid circle unaffected by any fill value.)*

Comment: Indeed, it was a simplified example of my use case where I have grouped data, other aesthetics and facets. Yet, your answer totally addressed my question, solved my problem and taught me how to deal better with these issues in the future. Awesome answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great answer there +